# get Forbidden resource even when the requested user is admin

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, nestjs, prisma

Middleware is used to protect the resolver. The middleware checks the role of user and despite the right role of the requested user I cannot access `listUser` query. I get following response

```
"errors": [
    {
      "message": "Forbidden resource",
      "extensions": {
        "code": "FORBIDDEN",
        "response": {
          "statusCode": 403,
          "message": "Forbidden resource",
          "error": "Forbidden"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

Here is my code

```
model User {
  id            String           @id @default(uuid())
  firstName     String
  lastName      String
  email         String           @unique
  username      String           @unique
  password      String
  confirm       Boolean          @default(false)
  isValid       Boolean          @default(false) @map("is_valid")
  isSuperuser   Boolean          @default(false)
  userRoles     UserRole[]

  @@unique([id, email])
}

model Role {
  id        String      @id @default(uuid())
  name      String      @unique
  createdAt DateTime?   @db.Timestamp()
  updatedAt DateTime?   @updatedAt @db.Timestamp()
  userRoles UserRole[]
}

model UserRole {
  id        String    @id @default(uuid())
  userId    String
  user      User      @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  roleId    String
  role      Role      @relation(fields: [roleId], references: [id])
  createdAt DateTime? @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime? @updatedAt @db.Timestamp()
}

@Injectable()
export class UserMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  constructor(
    private readonly prismaService: PrismaService,
    private readonly validationService: ValidationService,
  ) {}

  async use(req: any, res: any, next: () => void) {
    if (req.headers.authorization) {
      const { userId } = jwt.decode(
        String(req.headers.authorization).split(/ /g)[1],
      ) as JWT;
      const user = await this.prismaService.user.findFirst({
        where: { id: userId },
        include: { userRoles: true },
      });
      if (user && !user.confirm)
        throw new ForbiddenException('User not confirmed');

      if (user) {
        delete user.password;
        req.user = user;
        req.user.isAdmin = await this.validationService.isAdmin(userId);
      }
    }
    next();
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class ValidationService {
  constructor(private readonly prisma: PrismaService) {}

  async isAdmin(userId: string): Promise<boolean> {
    const u = await this.prisma.role.findUnique({
      where: { name: Role.Admin },
    });
    return await this.prisma.userRole
      .count({
        // could not find a way to access directly through role name instead of id
        where: { userId, roleId: u.id },
      })
      .then((count) => {
        return count ? true : false;
      });
  }
}

  @Query(() => UserPaginated)
  @Roles(Role.Admin)
  async listUsers(
    @Args('paginate', { nullable: true, defaultValue: { skip: 0, take: 50 } })
    paginate: PaginationArgs,
    @Args('order', {
      nullable: true,
      defaultValue: { orderBy: 'username', direction: 'desc' },
    })
    order: OrderListUsers,
    @Args('filter', { nullable: true })
    filter: FilterListUsers,
  ) {
    return await this.userService.list(paginate, order, filter);
  }
```

Why am I not able to access `listUser` with role as Admin ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your ValidationService has some problems. Please try this. But i should say that, this is not the perfect solution. Your table structure and prisma requests needs some improvements.

```
@Injectable()
export class ValidationService {
  constructor(private readonly prisma: PrismaService) {}

  async isAdmin(userId: string): Promise<boolean> {
    const u = await this.prisma.role.findUnique({
      where: { name: Role.Admin },
    });
    const userRoleCount = await this.prisma.userRole
      .count({
        where: { userId, roleId: u.id },
      });
    return userRoleCount > 0;
  }
}
```